# UIScrollView not scrollable vertically with storyboard(using autolayout)?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I just add a scroll view to the storyboard, and added two views on the top and bottom, and making the bottom some part outside of the view to make it scrollable, but it doesn't work, what I have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you are not using autolayout then you have to set content size manually programatically

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I am intended to use the auto layout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668417/uiscrollview-with-content-view/45669959#45669959

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView with Content View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668417/uiscrollview-with-content-view)

Answer (score 0):

Inside you scrollview add a view with fixed height constrains and inside that view you can add your subview according to your design.

You can also set content size of the scrollview from storyboard.

Comment: **Also set content size of the scrollview from storyboard.**   This is  not correct. Contentsize is calculated based on given constraints. So your first two lines is correct !! No need for that line

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using AutoLayout, then try to set `scrollview.contentSize = bottomview.frame.origin.y+bottomview.frame.size.height` This will make scrollview scrollable when device screen height is less than bottomViews bottom edge. In this make sure that your bottomview us immediate subview of scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

For scroll in scrollview you **need to give inner bound to scrollview with subview**.

[See image vertical scrolling with auto layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8taJ.png)

Your problem may be you not give top and bottom inner bound to scrollview.
Like you added 2 view then for **top view give top constraint** and for bottom view give **bottom constraints to scroll view**.
Now you **subviews height must be more then scrollview's height**.
Scrollview need inter bounds (scrollview to it's subview) to scroll for vertical (top and bottom) and for horizontal (left and right).